# как параметру присвоить код

Tags: flutter, dart

**1 ВАРИАНТ** разумеется работает

```
children: <Widget>[
 MyContainer('1', 75.0, 75.0, 0.0),
 MyContainer('2', 75.0, 75.0, 0.0),
 MyContainer('3', 75.0, 75.0, 0.0),
 MyContainer('4', 75.0, 75.0, 0.0),
 MyContainer('5', 75.0, 75.0, 0.0),
],
```

**2 ВАРИАНТ** работает

```
children: f1(),
```

```
List f1() {
 var ara = List<Widget>();
 for(int i=0; i<5;) {
  i++;
  ara.add(MyContainer(i.toString(), 75.0, 75.0, 0.0));
 }
 return ara;
}
```

**3 ВАРИАНТ** разумеется не работает. Как в 3 варианте вставить код и возможно ли такое? Спасибо.

```
children:
 for(int i=0; i<5;) {
  i++;
  MyContainer(i.toString(), 75.0, 75.0, 0.0);
 },
```

**полный пример кода**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
   debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
   title: 'Name App',
   theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
   ),
   home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
     //title: Text('Name Page'),
    ),
    body: MyHomePage(),
   ),
  );
 }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
   width: double.infinity,
   height: null,
   color: Colors.amber,
   child: Wrap(
    direction: Axis.horizontal,
    spacing: 10.0,
    runSpacing: 10.0,
    //1 ВАРИАНТ
    /*children: <Widget>[
     MyContainer('1', 75.0, 75.0, 0.0),
     MyContainer('2', 75.0, 75.0, 0.0),
     MyContainer('3', 75.0, 75.0, 0.0),
     MyContainer('4', 75.0, 75.0, 0.0),
     MyContainer('5', 75.0, 75.0, 0.0),
    ],*/

    children: f1(), //2 ВАРИАНТ

    //3 ВАРИАНТ не работает
    /*children:
     for(int i=0; i<5;) {
      i++;
      ara.add(MyContainer(i.toString(), 75.0, 75.0, 0.0));
     },*/
   ),
  );
 }
}

class MyContainer extends StatelessWidget {
 final String _str;
 final double _width;
 final double _height;
 final double _margin;

 MyContainer(this._str, this._width, this._height, this._margin);

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Container(
    width: _width,
    height: _height,
    margin: EdgeInsets.all(_margin),
    color: Colors.pink,
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    child: Text(
     _str,
     style: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.white,
      fontSize: 22.0,
     ),
    ),
   );
 }
}

List f1() {
 var ara = List<Widget>();
 for(int i=0; i<5;) {
  i++;
  ara.add(MyContainer(i.toString(), 75.0, 75.0, 0.0));
 }
 return ara;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 вариант не реализуемый, так как `children` может принимать только `List<Widget>`, а вы пытаетесь засунуть цикл.

---

2 вариант более предпочтительный нежели 1, так как, вы как программист должны автоматизировать тривиальные задачи.

И метод `f1()` по хорошему должен находиться внутри класса `MyHomePage`.

---

Цикл более правильно реализовать так:

```
for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
  MyContainer(i.toString(), 75.0, 75.0, 0.0);
}
```

---

Пытайтесь не использовать `var`, так как потом очень сложно определить что это за переменная (частая ошибка новичка).

Comment: Уважаемый MiT, огромное Вам спасибо! Если использовать i++ внутри круглых скобок цикла, то вывод i.toString() начинается с 0, а мне нужно с 1, поэтому я там и расположил.Еще раз спасибо!

Comment: @Anton ну так начинайте цикл с 1: `for(int i=1; i<5; i++)`